# Finding a cruise on the Nile

Tags: cruising, egypt

What's the best approach for finding a cruise on the Nile? Anything in particular that should look out for? How can you distinct good boats from bad?

Comment: Suggestion: Keep an eye on GroupOn, they have posted some great deals on Egyptian river cruises lately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did two days on a felluca (small sail boat) and I have some thoughts on this.

I personally loved sleeping on deck, watching everything go by.  But there were the big cruise ships as well.

On the big boats - you have more height, you have working toilets, I presume good meals, great cabins and beds, and so on.  But it'll be very touristy.

On the small fellucas, you sleep on mattresses with your sleeping bag, under the stars, eat food cooked in front of you sharing with your shipmates.  You pull to the side of the river to use the bathroom.  It's peaceful and serene.

I prefer the small boat option, but I can totally understand why some prefer the large ones.

That's probably a good start - figure out what type you want, and then go from there.  TNTMagazine in London has all sorts of ads for companies - Go Bus was who I used, and there's On The Go as well - never heard any really serious complaints about any Egypt tours though, and I know a lot of people who have been.  Lovely country!